# If user exit app and when open it start with first screen react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Issues:

I completed steps till adding the profile information and moved to the next screen which is contact information. I closed the app and opened it again....The app shows that I have created the profile now i need to do the next steps

Expected Result:
If the user leaves the process of profile creation, start over.

Comment: sorry didnt get what is to be done

Comment: Complete profile :In this If i have 5 screen and assume user reach  to 3 screen and when user exit app and start i want to start it 1 screen But instead when open it start with 3 screen ....How to fix it?

Comment: okay so with every step , are you storing some data somewhere?

Comment: yes i store data using api calls

Comment: export const saveOrganizationInfo = (data, token, id, navigation) => {
  return dispatch => {
    let headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    };
    axios
      .post(`${Url}api/users/organization-info`, data, {headers: headers})
      .then(resp => {
        let response = resp.data;
        dispatch(setLoader(false));
        navigation.navigate('confirmYourPhone', {phoneNo: data.phone});
        dispatch(getUserDetail(id));
      })
    );
  };
};

Comment: hey anjali can you post the above code in question itself?

Comment: Have you any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247556/discussion-between-anjali-deshmukh-and-gaurav-roy).

Answer (score 0):

so what you can do is :

In async storage, you can save the page name last where the user visited and data was stored and api responded succesfully, (https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage_

like :

```
const callApi = (pageName) => {

const result = await api()

//on sucess
if(result.status === 200){
  //store page name like this 
 await AsyncStorage.setItem('@page_name', pageName)
}

}
```

Then next time when you come back to app, check what page user was on last:

like :

```
 const checkForPageName = async() => {
    
     const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@page_name')
        if(value !== null) {
        
        if(value === "secondpage"){
    navigation.navigate("secondpage");
    }
    
       if(value === "thirdpage"){
    navigation.navigate("thirdpage");
    }
          
        } else{
    // this is first time user is coming
    
    navigation.navigate("FirstPage");
    }

    }
```

Hope it helps, feel free for doubts